# How add gradient color for MFC dialog box Button?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, mfc

I am trying to add color to button in dialog box. Using this code i was able to add to back ground, but i want to add color for button too.

[image: pass word dialog box]

```
void password::OnPaint()
{
    CPaintDC dc(this); 

    CRect rect;
    GetClientRect(&rect);

    int r1 = 127, g1 = 127, b1 = 56; //Any start color
    int r2 = 5, g2 = 155, b2 = 165; //Any stop color

    for (int i = 0; i<rect.Height(); i++)
    {
        int r, g, b;
        r = r1 + (i * (r2 - r1) / rect.Height());
        g = g1 + (i * (g2 - g1) / rect.Height());
        b = b1 + (i * (b2 - b1) / rect.Height());
        dc.FillSolidRect(0, i, rect.Width(), 1, RGB(r, g, b));
    }
}
```

Comment: The most direct way would be to add the `BS_OWNERDRAW` style to your button(s) and then, in your `password` (dialog box) class, override the `OnDrawItem()` method and handle the case(s) where the `nID` parameter corresponds to the button(s) concerned. You will have an `HDC` and a client rectangle for the button in the `pDIS` argument, and you can use similar code as you have given for drawing the background. (You would also need to draw the text and borders, though.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the color of the Button, you should draw it yourself. You should override the `CButton` class and add the virtual function `DrawItem`. The button should have the `BS_OWNERDRAW` style set.

I suggest you could refer to [this example on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cbutton-class?view=vs-2019#drawitem).